# Environment variables not setting in Python

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, gis, qgis

I'm trying to run a python script that requires certain environment variables be set. I'm currently running a .bat script that sets these environment variables and then calls the python script.

I'd like to get rid of the .bat script and set the required environment variables within the Python script.

This is what the .bat script looks like -

```
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18
SET QGISNAME=qgis
SET QGIS=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%QGIS%

CALL "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"

set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%QGIS%\bin;%PATH%
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27
set PYTHONPATH=%QGIS%\python;%PYTHONPATH%

python D:\temp\fran\NEW\new.py
```

Here is how I'm trying to mimic in Python -

```
import os
import subprocess

OSGEO4W_ROOT = r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18'
QGISNAME = r'qgis'
QGIS = r'{}\apps\{}'.format(OSGEO4W_ROOT,QGISNAME)
QGIS_PREFIX_PATH = '{}'.format(QGIS)

bat_command = [r'{}\bin\o4w_env.bat'.format(OSGEO4W_ROOT)]
subprocess.check_call(bat_command)

PATH = os.environ['PATH']
PYTHONPATH = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] 

os.environ['PATH'] = r'{}\bin;{}\bin;{}'.format(OSGEO4W_ROOT,QGIS,PATH)
os.environ ['PYTHONHOME'] = r'{}\apps\Python27'.format(OSGEO4W_ROOT)
os.environ ['PYTHONPATH'] = r'{}\python;{}'.format(QGIS,PYTHONPATH)

from qgis.core import (QgsProject, QgsComposition, QgsApplication, QgsMapLayerRegistry)
```

This is the error message I receive -

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

When I launch the script from the .bat file everything works. When I set environment variables in python and run I get an import error.

Any ideas?

Comment: If `o4w_env.bat` is supposed to be setting required environment variables, then this can't work. You're running it as a child process, and it can't modify the environment of its parent. You can hack this to make it 'work' by running the command `r'cmd.exe /u /c ""{}\bin\o4w_env.bat" & set"'.format(OSGEO4W_ROOT)`. using `subprocess.check_output`. Decode it as `'utf-16le'`, and then parse it to update `os.environ`. Or you could port `o4w_env.bat` to Python as well to directly modify the current process.

Comment: @eryksun thanks for the response. I'll try to mimic what o4w_env.bat is doing as well in Python.

Comment: You state that you get an import error, but you do not state what the error is.

Comment: @StephenRauch updated the main body. The error message is `ImportError: No module named site`

Answer (score 1):

You are stomping (not editing) `PYTHONPATH`. In the original batch file we have:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%QGIS%\python;%PYTHONPATH%
```

Note that this prepended another directory to the path.  Your code:

```
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = r'{}\python;'.format(QGIS,PYTHONPATH)
```

stomps the `PYTHONPATH`. You need something more like:

```
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = r'{}\python;'.format(QGIS) + PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: I had a mistake in my posted code. That statement should have been `os.environ ['PYTHONPATH'] = r'{}\python;{}'.format(QGIS,PYTHONPATH)`